# How can I develop and test a policy without breaking TFS for the whole team?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I'm working on a check in policy and while testing it the first time, I got an email from a teammate saying he couldn't commit any files, because when I installed the policy **for testing on my machine**, *his* TFS died, because he didn't have the policy DLL installed and registered. It seems that when I registered the policy locally, the TFS **server** registered it for the whole team, and the other members don't have it yet, so their commits blew up.

But how are you supposed to develop and test a policy if the only way to do this is installing in the global TFS server for everyone? Clearly, the policy code isn't ready for deployment before you ever try to test it, and you can't test it if testing breaks TFS for everyone until you test and deploy it.

What is the way out of this problem? Ideally, I'd like to have a local-only policy, but that doesn't seem to be possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Policies are set on a per Team Project basis. There is no local setting for check in policies, they are created against the Team Project and everyone who is using that Team Project will be affected, meaning that you will have to roll out the dll to all users.

Your best solution is to have a test Team Project where you can try out new builds / check-in policies and other bits and pieces in isolation.

Once you are happy with what you have, you can then apply the same items to the main Team Project that your team is working on.

[image: team project settings]

Comment: But since this is version control, doesn't that mean that the test project is retained forever? And what if the test project doesn't have the file complexity of the real project, so you can't really test? Do you have to clone a whole massive project for this one little use case? It really seems like it ought to be possible to have a local policy, for situations where one developer wants to explore something over time, against the real project.

Comment: the destroy command can be used to permanently delete something from TFS. you could just use a subset of data rather than the whole project.